# how to display display data from database into scrolledText widget of tkinter in python?

Tags: python, oracle, tkinter

I have created GUI fro student management system.I have added view button in it.Whenever it is clicked it displays data stored in student table but when it is clicked again instead of displaying records exactly once it displays records multiple time.
[!it is picture when clicked on view button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUt4X.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUt4X.png)

## gui for student management system

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext
root = Tk()
root.title("S.M.s")
root.geometry("300x300+300+300")
def f1():
    root.withdraw()
    addst.deiconify()
def f2():
    addst.withdraw()
    root.deiconify()
def f3():  
    root.withdraw()
    viewst.deiconify()
    import cx_Oracle
    con = None
    cursor = None
    try:
        con = cx_Oracle.connect("system/abc123")
        
        cursor = con.cursor()
        sql = "select * from student"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        msg = ""
        for d in data:
            msg = msg + "r: " +str(d[0]) +" n: "+ d[1] + "\n"
            stData.insert(INSERT,msg)
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error window" ,e)
        
    finally:
        if cursor is not None:
            cursor.close()
        if con is not None:
            con.close()
        
        

def f4():
    viewst.withdraw()
    root.deiconify()
def f5():
    import cx_Oracle
    con = None
    cursor = None

    try:
        con = cx_Oracle.connect("system/abc123")
        rno = int(entRno.get())
        name = entName.get()
        cursor = con.cursor()
        sql = "insert into student values('%d','%s')"
        args = (rno,name)
        cursor.execute(sql % args)
        con.commit()
        msg = str(cursor.rowcount) + "records inserted "
        entRno.delete(0,END)
        entName.delete(0,END)
        entName.focus()
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error window" ,e)
        con.rollback()
    finally:
        if cursor is not None:
            cursor.close()
        if con is not None:
            con.close()

btnAdd = Button(root,text = "Add",font=("arial",18,"bold"),width = 10,command= f1)
btnView = Button(root,text="View",font = ("arial",18,"bold"),width =10,command = f3)

btnAdd.pack(pady=10)
btnView.pack(pady=10)

addst = Toplevel(root)
addst.title("Add s")
addst.geometry("400x300+300+200")
addst.withdraw()

lblRno = Label(addst,text = "enter rno",font = ("arial",18,"bold"))
entRno = Entry(addst,bd =5,font =("arial",18,"bold"))
lblName = Label(addst,text = "enter name",font=("arial",18,"bold"))
entName = Entry(addst,bd=5,font=("arial",18,"bold"))
btnAddSave= Button(addst,text = "Save",font = ("arial",18,"bold"),command = f5)
btnAddBack = Button(addst,text = "Back",font = ("arial",18,"bold"),command = f2)
lblRno.pack(pady = 5)
entRno.pack(pady=5)
lblName.pack(pady=5)
entName.pack(pady=5)
btnAddSave.pack(pady=5)
btnAddBack.pack(pady=5)

viewst = Toplevel(root)
viewst.title("View S")
viewst.geometry("400x300+300+200")
viewst.withdraw()

stData= scrolledtext.ScrolledText(viewst,width=40,height=10)
btnViewBack = Button(viewst,text = "Back",font = ("arial",18,"bold"),command = f4)

stData.pack()
btnViewBack.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The text widget has a method for deleting existing text. Have you tried to use it?

Comment: Insert a condition into `def f3()`, only read from database the **first** time.

Comment: @stovfl I wanted to do same but not getting how to do

Comment: @BryanOakley yes i tried delete(0,END) method but it is only for entry widget i am displaying data from database into scrolledtext widget and want to display data exaclty once.

Comment: @DivyaBorse ***"not getting how to do"***: Do you not know to write a `condition` or what else do you need *how to*?

Comment: @DivyaBorse: no, `delete` isn't only for the entry widget. However, for the text widget it's `delete("1.0", END)`. Indexes for the text widget are different than for the entry widget since the text widget can have more than one line.